# Dynamic column names in group_by statements in R

Tags: r, dynamic

I am facing an issue in dealing with the dynamic column names in R.I want to group my data by Date_var (which is a dynamic variable) and a dynamically created column name. Following is my code

```
Date_Var="D_APP_MTH" 
Scores_Used=c("s_app","vedascore","vedascore_2_0_cr")

for(i in 1:length(Scores_Used)){
  Score_Stability<-Portfolio_Final%>%
  group_by(Date_Var,paste("score_bin",Scores_Used[i],"all",sep="_"))%>%
  tally
  assign(paste("Score_Stability",Scores_Used[i],"All",sep="_"),Score_Stability,.GlobalEnv)
}
```

But i am getting an error. Can anyone help me how to use a dynamic column and a dynamically named column  in the group by statement.

Comment: there are a few issues with this code...including the error might help us

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the issue solved

```
  library(dplyr)
  Score_Stability<-Portfolio_Final%>%
    group_by_(eval(Date_Var),paste("score_bin",Scores_Used[i],"all",sep="_"))%>%
    tally
```

assign(paste("Score_Stability",Scores_Used[i],"All",sep="_"),Score_Stability,.GlobalEnv)